# Vector and vector fields on a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry

*One's ordinary idea of a curve is that it is a continuous series of points in $M$. It is convenient to make a somewhat different definition: a curve is a (differentiable) mapping from an open set of $\mathbb{R^1}$ into $M$ (see Figure 2.8).*

[image: Image 1]

*Thus, one associates with each point of $\mathbb{R^1}$ (which is a real number, say $\lambda$) a point in $M$, which is called the image point of $\lambda$. The set of all image points is the ordinary notion of the curve, but our definition gives each point a value of $\lambda$. Clearly we have a parameterized
curve, with parameter $\lambda$. Thus, two curves are different even if they have the same image in $M$, provided they assign a different parameter value to the image points. A function on $M$ is a rule that assigns a real number (the value of the function) to each point of $M$. When a region of $M$ is mapped differentiably onto a region of $\mathbb{R^n}$, the function becomes a function on $\mathbb{R^n}$ (see Figure 2.9).*

[image: Image 2]

*If this function is differentiable in $\mathbb{R^n}$, then it is said to be a differentiable function on $M$. We can say the same thing in another way: abstractly, the function may be written as $f(P)$, where $P$ is a point of $M$. But $P$ has coordinates, so one can express the value of the function by some algebraic expression $f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$*

1) I just want to clarify, $f(P)$ is the image point of $M$ so that $f(P)$ is a point in $\mathbb{R^1}$ such that $f(P) = \lambda$ where $\lambda$ is an element of $\mathbb{R^1}$. But since $P$ has coordinates $(x_1,...,x_n)$, the function can also be viewed as a mapping from $\mathbb{R^n}$ to $\mathbb{R^1}$ such that $f(x_1,...,x_n) = \lambda$? So basically, the image is always in $\mathbb{R^1}$ but its domain can be viewed in two ways since there is an invertible mapping $g$ from $M$ and $\mathbb{R^n}$?

*Consider a curve passing through the point $P$ of $M$, described by the
equations $x^i =x^i(\lambda), i = 1, ... , n.$*

2) Are these set of equations a mapping from $\mathbb{R^1}$ to $\mathbb{R^n}$?

*Consider also a differentiable function $f(x_1,...,x_n)$ (abbreviated $f(x_i)$) on $M$. At each point of the curve, $f$ has a value. Therefore, along the curve there is a differentiable function $g(\lambda)$ which gives the value of $f$ at the point whose parameter value is $\lambda$.
$$g(\lambda) = f(x_1,...,x_n)$$*

3) I'm already confused for this last paragraph. $f(x_1,...,x_n)$ is a mapping from $\mathbb{R^n}$ to $\mathbb{R^1}$, but I don't understand what is meant by "Therefore, along the curve there is a differentiable function $g(\lambda)$ which gives the value of $f$ at the point whose parameter value is $\lambda$". How can the image point $g(\lambda)$ (which I assume to be a mapping from $\mathbb{R^1}$ to $\mathbb{R^n}$ since its domain is $\lambda$ and from figure 2.9 $g$ is mapped to $\mathbb{R^n}$) be equal to $f(x_1,...,x_n)$ if $f$ is a mapping from $\mathbb{R^n}$ to $\mathbb{R^1}$ which means $f(x_1,...,x_n)$ is a point in $\mathbb{R^1}$?

Comment: Good-natured suggestion: Write down a particular plane curve (such as $c(\lambda) = (\lambda, 0)$ or $c(\lambda) = (\lambda^{3}, 0)$ or $c(\lambda) = (\cos\lambda, \sin\lambda)$) and a particular function (such as $f(x, y) = x^{2} - y^{2}$), and interpret each of your questions for this curve/function. Then see if any confusion remains, and if so, focus your question to the remaining issue(s).

Answer (score 1):

Your confusion comes (I think) mainly from the abuse of notation. I try to make this a bite more precise and clearer for you.

We have a smooth manifold $M$. It's important to see that $M$, besides being a topological space with certain properties, is a set. So we can define functions from $M$ to another set and vice versa, e.g. a curve $c:I\subset \mathbb{R}\to M$ or a real valued function $f:M\to \mathbb{R}$. Furthermore (by definition) we have for each $p \in M$ a neighborhood $U$ of $p$ and homeomorphism $x:U \to V\subset \mathbb{R}^n, q \mapsto x(q)=(x^1(q),...,x^n(q)).$ You can think that creatures living on the manifold use these maps to make a model\map of the world they're living in (as we humans make maps (lie in a plane) of our round globe). Now of course we can have a look at the composition of maps. For example
$$f\circ x^{-1}:V \to \mathbb{R}, (x^1,...,x^n)\mapsto f(x^{-1}(x^1,...,x^n))$$ (pay attention: when considerin the map $x:U\to V\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, $x^i(q)$ denotes the i-th coordinate of the point $q$ gets mapped to. But when considering the composition $(x^1,...x^n)$ is a point in the n-dim. euclidean space) or $$f\circ c: I\to \mathbb{R},t \mapsto f(c(t)).$$
So your $f(x^1,...,x^n)$ is actually abuse of notation for $(f\circ x^{-1})(x^1,...,x^n).$

So now to answer your questions:
1) You're right, the image of $f$ always lies in $\mathbb{R}.$ I would not say that the domain can be viewed in two ways, but one could probably argue about that. But for me $f$ is a map from $M$ into the real numbers and $f(x^1,...,x^n)=(f\circ x^{-1})(x^1,...,x^n)$ is only its local representation, which I don't see as the map itself, because it depends on your chart $(U,x).$ (However I think that's more a matter of taste and that there are other people who would say that the domain can be seen in two ways.)

2) Written as this it a set of equations. Be aware that this set of equations is the local representation of your curve, i.e. $x^i=x^i(t)=x^i(c(t))=\text{i-th coordinate of } x(c(t)). $

3) I think your confusion comes from the (probably not intended) fact that the author has choosen $g$ for what I call $x$ and also $g$ for what I call $f\circ c$. I don't think that this $g$ shouldn't have anything to do with the $g$ that "creatures living on $M$ use to make a model of their world".

Comment: Jackel I understand what you're pointing out, your $x$ is the $g$ of the author,I know that $f(x^1, ..., x^n)$ should be written as $(f o g^{-1}) (x^1, ..., x^n)$, but after reading what you've said, I already knew that could cause some confusion and that doesn't answer my question. My question is, $g(\lambda)$ and $f(x^1, ..., n^n)$ are different image points in different "space". $g$ always maps to $\mathbb{R^n}$, $f(x^1, ..., x^n)$ or $(f o g^{-1}) (x^1, ..., x^n)$ always maps to $\mathbb{R^1}$. Maybe you could clarify/rephrase the last paragraph. How about my 1) 2) questions?

Comment: I tried to rephrase the last paragraph and really tried to answer your question. I hope that it can now answer them. If not I probably didn't understand where your confusion is.

Comment: My point is, given the confusion with notation is cleared, that wouldn't settle the fact that the equality above question 3) is confusing since the left hand side's domain is $\lambda$, so for sure it is a mapping FROM $\mathbb{R^1}$ to whatever it is. The left hand side is a mapping TO $\mathbb{R^1}$.

Comment: Even if we replace $g$ from $g(\lambda)$, the fact is still there that it doesn't match the image point $f(x^1,...,x^n)$ since it is an element of $\mathbb{R^1}$; unless however, the mapping on the left side is a mapping from $\mathbb{R^1}$ to $\mathbb{R^1}$. But that wouldn't make any sense based on the discussion.

Comment: As I have said the $g$ with $g(t)=f(x^1,...,x^n)=f(x^1(t),...,x^n(t))=(f\circ x^{-1}\circ x \circ c)(t)=f(c(t))$ has nothing to do with the $g:U\subset M \to V\subset \mathbb{R}^n.$ Observe that $f:M\to \mathbb{R}$ and $c:I\subset \mathbb{R}\to M$, so the composition is a map from the real numbers into the real numbers $f\circ c:I\to \mathbb{R}.$

Comment: If you put it that way then all makes sense, but then using $g$ is not an abuse of notation, it's completely wrong. An example of abuse of notation would be writing $f(x^1,...,x^n)$ instead of $(f o g^{-1})(x^1,...,x^n)$.